# HttpRequest with JAVA (libGdx) and processing it with PHP

Tags: java, php, post, libgdx, httprequest

I could really use some help here.
I'm learning HttpRequest with libGDX, and I'm stuck with the setContent();
Here is the Java code I'm trying to run. And it works fine, except one little problem: It doesn't send the variables "name" and "score" to the httptest.php file. However the php file runs normaly, inserting empty values into the database.
Eclipse even shows me the result about the success with an empty name and a 0 score:

```
Status code : 200
Result : connected succesfully inserted and his score: 0
```

So it looks like the two programs communicate, except the java doesn't send the data to the php.
I run out of ideas, and dont know what to do.

The java code:

```
 Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("name", "testname1");
        parameters.put("score", "56");
       HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST);
       request.setUrl("www.myurl.com/httptest.php");

       request.setContent(HttpParametersUtils.convertHttpParameters(parameters));
    //   request.setContent("name=testname&score=10");

       Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new HttpResponseListener() {
               @Override
               public void handleHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                       Gdx.app.log("Status code ", "" + httpResponse.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                       Gdx.app.log("Result ", httpResponse.getResultAsString());
               }
               @Override
               public void failed(Throwable t) {
                       Gdx.app.log("Failed ", t.getMessage());
               }
       });
```

The php code:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$scoreget=$_POST["score"];
$score=(int)$scoreget;
if (is_int ($score))
{
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($mycon);

// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
  else{echo"connected ";}

$sql= "INSERT INTO scores (name, score, text) VALUES ('$name', '$score','')";
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }else{
    echo "succesfully inserted ".$name." and his score: ".$score;
        }
}else{
echo "Invalid numeric type";
}   
?>
```

I also tested the httptest.php with this form and it works fine:

```
<html> 
<body>
<form action="httptest.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Score: <input type="text" name="score"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the Java code you have a line commented out. Does it work with that line?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That was my first try, I copied from an example file I found on the internet, and I don't understand why it isn't working...

Comment: Does `file_get_contents('php://input');` return anything?

Comment: I dont know where should i insert this:    file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: Oh and when I set the content this way:     request.setContent("name=testname&score=10"); , and I use GET method instead of POST, then the PHP gets the correct values and works fine.

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input');` returns a string, insert it into your php script and echo the result.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you correctly set the Content-Type header on the request?

```
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I'm wondering if PHP doesn't part the parameters in a POST body unless the correct content type is present.